# Why Spark explain these two query differently?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

So I have these two queries to achieve the same goal. Using Spark-SQL.

Query A:

```
SELECT * FROM inspex.defect_parquet a
INNER JOIN inspex.layer_parquet b
ON a.id = b.id 
AND b.name = 'Example1';
```

Query B:

```
SELECT * FROM inspex.defect_parquet 
WHERE inspex.layer_scan_index  
IN    (SELECT layer_scan_index
      FROM inspex.layer_parquet
      WHERE name = 'Example1');
```

`defect_parquet` is a pretty large table and `layer_parquet` is a small table with several hundreds kb.

Query B is 80% faster than A. And when I see the explanation of how Spark run this. Here is for Query A:[image]
Here is for Query B: [image]

Seems like Spark handles these differently. Could someone explain this to me? And why is Query B faster?

Comment: quite interesting.. by having a first look at your queries seems like  your second query filters the dataset to minimal and it passes  to big data select(via broadcasthashjoin hence small broadcast result size ). That's why its quick . but surprising fact is for loading 7 027 202 rows its showing different timings(13.2 sec for first query and 3.2 sec) for big dataset i.e  `inspex.defect_parquet` in your 2 stat diagrams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that statistics tells everything:

- both version uses broadcast join
- however, in  the second query you make project in subquery, so the output table is much smaller - that causes much smaller broadcast size and shorter time
- first query tries to pre-filter large dataset, however without many changes - dataset is still big, so this optimization only slows down your query number one

Comment: what does 'project' mean exactly?

Comment: @Jesse Projection means that only few columns are chosen from all columns. So not full source dataset is sent, but only few selected columns. In SQL Projection is in SELECT

Comment: I think your 3rd point might be the reason. Because I checked the explanation again and found out after projection columns doesn't seem to be much less. However Query B avoids the filter in the big table. Thanks.